# Change font-size without affecting div parent height

Tags: css

I am changing the font-size in a div.

The problem is that if I ask to set the font size bigger, the container div is resizing.

I ask in the css to scroll the content so why is this div resizing ?

```
.tileText {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 overflow-y: scroll;
 width: 70%;
 height: 100%;
 padding: 20px;
 color: #05083c;
 font-size: 1rem;
 border-radius: 5px;
 font-weight: 400;
 line-break: anywhere;
 white-space: pre-wrap;
 overflow-wrap: break-word;
 background-color: white;
 box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/70bsL2yp/8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tileText is actually the container in which you've got your text. so add the `max-height: 5rem;` to `.tileText{}` and Voila! problem solved:

```
.tileText {
  ...
  ...
  max-height: 5rem;
}
```

or you can specify the `.tileText` height in another unit like rem rather than percentages.

.tileText {
...
...
height: 10rem;
}

Comment: It's not completely responsive sinse I wanted to keep the % ratio from the container... but with some js logic I changed the max-height with conditions

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because you need to provide a specific height in terms of pixel, vh, rem or em. Since you have specified it in terms of percentage, its not working.

The problem exist in the body height, since you haven't explicitly specified any height to the body, body will have height as auto, that means it will always occupy the height as per the content height, but then your `.container` have 80% height as well as `.tileText` also have 80% height, which is being derived from body, but since your body doesn't have any specific height, the 80% of the container isn't working and the same is happening for the `.tileText` element. But the problem can be solved by defining the height by any unit other than %, since % values are derived from the parent you need to avoid it or else you have to specify the height for the body.

So instead of using the percentage use any of these values, like this:

```css
.tileText {
  .
  .
  .
  height: 200px;
}
```

Here I have used 200px you can use anything like, 10rem, 20vh, etc.

Comment: but I need the height to be responsive

Comment: Based on what? viewport height? If yes, then there is vh unit which can help you with it, use 20vh for the height, it will take up 20% of the viewport height, which will scale or scale down according to height of viewport